# dplyr filter and then mutate while retaining all data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that has an id for every mother infant "dyad". I would like to create a new variable that only uses data from the infant variables. This is simple by using the dplyr::filter function. However, using filter means that the mother data is lost. Is there a way to filter, then mutate, while still retaining all the data?

Example:

```
require(tidyverse)

dataSet <- data.frame(dyad_id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                      dyad = c("Mom","Mom","Inf","Inf","Mom","Mom","Inf","Inf","Mom","Mom","Inf","Inf"),
                      timepoint = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                      v1 = c(3,4,5,2,4,6,3,67,8,4,3,2),
                      v2 = c(6,8,3,4,5,6,1,3,4,5,6,7))

dataSet <- dataSet %>% 
dplyr::filter(dyad == "Inf") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(v3 = v1 + v2)
```

When I run this, it removes all the maternal data from the dataset:

```
> dataSet
  dyad_id dyad timepoint v1 v2 v3
1       1  Inf         1  5  3  8
2       1  Inf         2  2  4  6
3       2  Inf         1  3  1  4
4       2  Inf         2 67  3 70
5       3  Inf         1  3  6  9
6       3  Inf         2  2  7  9
```

Desired output:

```
   dyad_id dyad timepoint v1 v2 v3
1        1  Mom         1  3  6 NA
2        1  Mom         2  4  8 NA
3        1  Inf         1  5  3 8
4        1  Inf         2  2  4 6
5        2  Mom         1  4  5 NA
6        2  Mom         2  6  6 NA
7        2  Inf         1  3  1 4
8        2  Inf         2 67  3 70
9        3  Mom         1  8  4 NA
10       3  Mom         2  4  5 NA
11       3  Inf         1  3  6 9
12       3  Inf         2  2  7 9
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the if_else function in dplyr:

```
require(tidyverse)

dataSet <- data.frame(dyad_id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                      dyad = c("Mom","Mom","Inf","Inf","Mom","Mom","Inf","Inf","Mom","Mom","Inf","Inf"),
                      timepoint = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                      v1 = c(3,4,5,2,4,6,3,67,8,4,3,2),
                      v2 = c(6,8,3,4,5,6,1,3,4,5,6,7))

dataSet <- dataSet %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(v3 = if_else(dyad == "Inf",v1 + v2,0))


> head(dataSet)
  dyad_id dyad timepoint v1 v2 v3
1       1  Mom         1  3  6  0
2       1  Mom         2  4  8  0
3       1  Inf         1  5  3  8
4       1  Inf         2  2  4  6
5       2  Mom         1  4  5  0
6       2  Mom         2  6  6  0
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Only problem is I would like the "Mom" v3 variables to be NA rather than 0. This is the error I get when I change "0" to NA in the mutate function:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `v3`.
x `false` must be a double vector, not a logical vector.
ℹ Input `v3` is `if_else(dyad == "Inf", v1 + v2, NA)`.

Comment: You can keep it as a zero and then add this line 
       dataSet[dataSet$dyad=="Mom","v3"] = NA

Comment: Also, Infant is not a variable but a set of rows (or observations). "dyad" is the variable

Answer (score 2):

We can use `case_when` which would by default returns `NA` for the default case

```
library(dplyr)
dataSet %>%
    mutate(v3 = case_when(dyad == 'Inf' ~ v1 + v2))
```

-output

```
#    dyad_id dyad timepoint v1 v2 v3
#1        1  Mom         1  3  6 NA
#2        1  Mom         2  4  8 NA
#3        1  Inf         1  5  3  8
#4        1  Inf         2  2  4  6
#5        2  Mom         1  4  5 NA
#6        2  Mom         2  6  6 NA
#7        2  Inf         1  3  1  4
#8        2  Inf         2 67  3 70
#9        3  Mom         1  8  4 NA
#10       3  Mom         2  4  5 NA
#11       3  Inf         1  3  6  9
#12       3  Inf         2  2  7  9
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand it is somewhat frowned upon to answer with {data.table} on {tidyverse} questions, but I'll leave it here since it is quite conveniently implemented in data.table

```
library(data.table)
dataSet <- as.data.table(dataSet)

dataSet[filter_column == 'filter_value', mutate_column := 'mutate_value']
```

Every row that does not satisfy the filter condition will have an NA assigned to it on mutate_column (or in case the column already existed, it will leave those values unchanged)

So, in your case:

```
dataSet[dyad == 'Inf', v3 := v1 + v2]
```

You can then go back to piping dplyr functions immediately and your dataset will become a tibble again, leaving no footprint of the data.table operation.